# How can I remap the Eject key to Key J in OS X?

Tags: macos, button-remapping

I already have the KeyRemap4MacBook and need private.xml that will do this. I read the manual and tried a few things with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConsumerToKey:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>ejecttoj</name>
    <identifier>ejecttoj</identifier>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, KeyCode::J</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Eject keys have a small delay by default, but you can remove it with [NoEjectDelay](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/noejectdelay.html.en).

- [Documentation for private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en)
- [Key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data)
- [Predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml)

Comment: Thanks Lauri but what about the shift modifier to change small j to caps J?

Comment: It also changes for example shift+eject to shift+J unless you add `| ModifierFlag::NONE`.